# Get profile info from Android LinkedIn SDK

Tags: android, linkedin-api

How to get profile information from android Linkedin SDK?
I logged in using Linkedin SDK but i'm unable to get profile information.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513859/how-to-implement-login-with-linkedin-with-oauth-2-0-in-android

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIn has released latest SDK for all the platform, you can use that and get the profile of users, below is the code of the same,

```
String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name)";

APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
apiHelper.getRequest(this, url, new LinkedInConnection.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
        // Success!
    }

    @Override
    public void onApiError(LIApiError liApiError) {
        // Error making GET request!
    }
});
```

Also you can refer following url for detail,
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

Comment: btw, you can add LinkedIn SDK via gradle: https://github.com/Yazon2006/LinkedIn-auth-sample