# How to Integrate android app with linkedin signin?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates

From the above link I got information that 
**Authentication, SDKs, and Plugins: SDKs: Our JavaScript and Mobile Software Development Kits (SDKs) will stop working. Developers will need to migrate to using OAuth 2.0 directly from their apps.**

I want to add linkedin login in my android app. The only way seems to be is using oauth2 login, but it requires a backend change. I need to add an end point which will get the end point from oauth response and again request the info and store in some permanent storage. Then I have to call the backend from android app to fetch that info.
**or **
Is there any alternative way to do that without backend change?

Comment: please look at the Refresh Token and Access Token more info check the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow#step-5-refresh-access-token

Comment: @ViralPatel the question is about can it be implemented without a backend change

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use 3rd party libs, I've created a lightweight "unofficial" SDK for Android, you can use it from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/AbdAllahAbdElFattah13/LinkedIn-SDK-Android.

It's unofficial because - as you mentioned - LinkedIn has deprecated and stopped supporting their old mobile SDKs.

We also use it in our production apps, so it should be working fine. :)

Answer (score -1):

As Linkedin document say:

> The LinkedIn API uses OAuth 2.0 for user authorization and API
>   authentication. Applications must be authorized and authenticated
>   before they can fetch data from LinkedIn or get access to member data.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57643213/8770663) and [this](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/linkedin).

I hope be useful for you.